# What permissions are needed to add/edit work items in TFS

Tags: tfs

I would like to grant my Q/A team permissions to create an edit bugs in TFS.  I could just throw them into the Contributors group, but I would rather create a Q/A group and assign it permissions specific to creating work items.  What permissions do I need to grant them.  (TFS 2008)

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if the security configuration were in one place and intuitive.  Instead, it's all over the place :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's actually going to be found under Area security.  Within VS 2008:

1. In Team Explorer, click on the appropriate team project that you want to check/change
2. Choose the `Team-->Team Project Settings-->Areas and Iterations` menu.
3. choose the appropriate area.  If you don't have any defined, or you want it to apply to all of them, choose the "Area" node.
4. Click on the `Security...` button.
5. The permissions to edit work items is set here:  `Edit work items in this node`