# Specific work item permissions

Tags: tfs

I'm kind of new to Team Foundation Server and am currently trying to find out where I can find the following security permissions:

- Assigning Work Items
- Deleting Work Items

I found out that I can allow or deny the editing and viewing of Work items in general, like described in this thread [What permissions are needed to add/edit work items in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919341/what-permissions-are-needed-to-add-edit-work-items-in-tfs) , here:

[image]

but I would like to go a bit more specific with that. I want to allow users to edit items but not to remove them or to change their assignment.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to edit the Work Item Template to add some custom Rules.

To restrict "Assigning" you would use a rule like this:

```
<FIELD name="State">
    <READONLY for="[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Valid Users"/>
</FIELD>
```

Work items can only be deleted by Project Administrators via the Command line - and if you try to restrict them from deleting stuff, you will find they probably just grant themselves delete if they need to.

There's a load more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404857.aspx#restrict).