# Error while trying to run project: Access is denied

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, access-denied

Trying to Start a Winform solution *With Debugging* in Visual Studio 2017 causes this error:

> Error while trying to run project: Access is denied.

[image]

Running *Without Debugging* works and starts the project without the error.

[image]

This guy reported the same issue with a WPF project to Microsoft Developer Community (beta testing) but there is no solution: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/39737/error-while-trying-to-run-project-unable-to-start-3.html

A [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) Trace reveals its an Access Denied in the Registry:

```
39:45.7
devenv.exe
RegCreateKey    \REGISTRY\A\{3883977B-E889-4804-9494-B5A8BC8E3F1D}\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_8708a912\DialogPage
ACCESS DENIED
Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
```

Since its an Application Hive Registry Key it cannot be changed in RegEdit. **UPDATE:** You can change this, see my updated answer.

How can I debug projects?

<sub>Note: Answering my own question to help others in the future.</sub>

Answer (score 12):

Right click on the Winform or WPF Project > Properties > Debug tab > tick Enable native code debugging.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
 Use this answer to  fix the Registry A Hive in VS2017 (it has its own registry):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45579640/495455

Comment: that's a strange solution for such problem [scratching head]. I've almost asked if you are running VS as admin, but I'd never expected this checbox to make a difference

Comment: Totally! It took me a lot of trial and error to work this out, usually troubleshooting gives you clues to help diagnose problems and narrow down the issue, for this one as you can see I took a complete stab in the dark. The Start Without Debugging was the only thing I had to go on.

Answer (score 2):

Go to project property change the target framework version and try it once for me it worked.

Comment: Oh wow this is the one that worked for me. I been getting this access denied problem on and off and its been such a roadblock. This clear the issue out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this extremely annoying problem for a couple weeks and I would keep rebuilding my project and copying over the vb code and design code to do a crappy work around.

**Today I finally found the root cause of my problem!!!!!**

I have a resource folder with images including some of my icon images

In my forms i reference these images from my resource folder

In some rare cases instead of referencing my project resource file i would import from local and select the same image from my local drive with **THE SAME NAME**.

Apparently it confused the builder and i was able to get my project back operational by deleting the .ico image that was under each form on the solution explorer tree that had imported image files from local and referencing the images from my resource folder​ instead

Answer (score -2):

Delete the item that you have recently added in your project file.then run the program

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Try changing the Application Type in project properties to Console Application. When the application type is Windows Forms app, your antivirus might think you are trying to run a malicious content.